# need to add posts per page to custom template in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, posts

im using the following code:

```
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php $posts = get_posts(array('cat' => 2)); ?> 
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
                <div class="span6 panel slide_toggle 
                    <?php
                    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
                        echo $category->slug . ' ';
                    }
                    ?>
                ">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail', 350,290,true); ?>
                        <div class="title slide_up">
                            <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

however im struggling to get the posts_per_page function in wordpress working having read up abit and using he parameters id normally use for my posts pages i dont seem to be getting anywhere.

i want the posts per page to show all as its currently restricted to 5. which i understand would be

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=-1'); ?>
```

Comment: try this ==> get_posts(array('cat' => 2, 'posts_per_page' => 5));

Comment: yes that works perfectly (when set to -1) thankyou!

Comment: when you not want Pagination

Comment: Why you use wp_reset_query();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ){
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        }
        elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { 
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
        }
        else {
            $paged = 1;
        }

        $args = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged));
        if($args->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while ($args->have_posts()) : $args->the_post(); ?>

           // Your Post goes here

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
             <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
             <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>
```

Hope this will help you